# Bootstrap modal not displayed in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login screen inside modal. That modal is called through anchor inside the menu

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" id="openLoginPopUp" data-remote="/Resources/Widgets/firstloginPopup.htm" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
```

But in mobile alone the modal is not displayed properly. Problem facing in modals are:

1. Sometimes only the modals top-margin color alone displays.
2. First screen (Guest login displays) but on clicking "Login with password" the next screen is displayed blank.
3. Some times even the guest (1st) screen itself becomes blank.
   But all these errors disappear once the screen is rotated or screen is adjusted.

I tried changing the css with jQuery but it didn't help. All other modals are working fine except this. Where am I going wrong please help.

Refer: http://stage.cbazaar.com

Comment: may be because this one has alot JS code, modal opens and then white screen and then again load the content so basically after loading modal JS code is doing it's job so remove the JS and see if the issue still there or not.

Comment: Please check media query if anything is interfering, please be aware that the modal uses `z-index` in your body, don't fiddle other elements directly under body with position absolute and z-index if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Hi Shehary and Daniel , Thanks for the reply,
Shehary: There really is lots of .js but most of it is for input validations only 
Daniel : As far as I'm concerned we haven't altered position and z-index.

To my knowledge as far as i debugged all the element's have the perfect display block and hide respectively but the height of those DIVs are 0 .

Comment: Daniel: As you have said i guess its the position issue , the plugin used for the menu is conflicting in modal. So some time even the scrolling is not possible in the modal
The designer team used mm-menu plugin i guess that is the reason but don't know how to find the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi After many attempts as per the bootstrap official note that

> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div

Read the Option named as "**remote**" [Bootstrap official link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options)!

So i have made the html inline rather than calling as a remote url